# Cannot call method 'lookup' of undefined when saving model in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

im using [LSA](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/) as my application adapter. im trying to update a model but i get an error that say

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lookup' of undefined ember-data.js:231
```

i have a controller and in actions of controller i write these codes :

```
 al:function(id){
        console.log(this.store.find('axisModel'));
        this.store.find('axisModel',id).then(function(item){
            item.set('orderId','1000');
            item.save();
            //console.log(item);
        });
    },
```

i have access to store and store can find a record and when i set orderId it set on ui but when i try `item.save()` for saving in localstorage i get an error.my ember-data verison is *v1.0.0-beta.1-39-g80dcf42* and ember version is *v1.0.0* . if i comment `item.save()` the ui was update but the model in local storage dosent update and if i uncomment this i get an error .

**Update**

i update the ember.js and ember-data to canary version and now every thing work correctly

Comment: Would you please move your Update into an Answer and accept it so this question doesn't show up as unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

i update the ember.js and ember-data to canary version and now every thing work correctly